# call cuda kernel from a multithreaded c application

Tags: multithreading, cuda

I've programmed a least squares optimization for CUDA. It works fine when it optimizes one data-set. For further use I have to implement it for a usage of three data-sets at the same time.
The code consists of three kernels and some host code between them to prepare data etc.
A simple implementation would be to call the program three times for every data set.

[image: serial compuatation]

But my task is to find out, how I can run it three times at the same time.
[image: multithreaded]

Is it possible or even a good idea to call the program or concurrent kernels from three host threads at the same time when I use libraries like openmp or posix? Or should I try to program an own scheduler?

Comment: If you acknowledge that the GPU is the throughput bottleneck and won't be able to process multiple data sets in parallel, then by definition your section picture can't happen. So what are you really trying to achieve here?

Comment: You could show more details including hardware specs., kernel lauch config, shared mem usage, etc., to get more specific answer.

Comment: @Eric: I run the kernels with a blockdim of (32,3,3) and a shared memory size of 9984 bytes. It will use as many blocks as the kernel need to comoute a given number of points - it will be blocks = pointcount / 32. My gpu is a 560ti.

Comment: @talonmies: the main question for me is, is there any thing to consider, if I start concurrent kernels from diffrent host threads? Assuming that I can reduce the shared memory to make it possible to run three concurrent kernels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "four blocks at the same time", do you mean four blocks per Multi-processor(MP)?

According to your additional comments in the Q, you probably has 384/32=12 Multi-processors(MPs) on your [560 Ti](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-560ti/specifications). If you launch more than 12*4=48 blocks for one kernel, you won't be able to run your three kernels concurrently.

In this case, the scale of your task is too large for [concurrent kernel execution](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#conurrent-kernel-execution), but you may still be able to overlap the data transfer and the kernel exeicution as shown in [this blog](https://developer.nvidia.com/content/how-overlap-data-transfers-cuda-cc).

You can find more info in the section [Asynchronous Concurrent Execution](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#asynchronous-concurrent-execution) of the CUDA programming guide.

On the other hand, since you also have some host code for each dataset, you could speed up your program by running host code of one dataset and kernel of another dataset concurently.

For host code parallelism, you could use posix/omp, and then bind each kernel with a different CUDA stream to the corresponding host thread.

Comment: It was four blocks per sm. The limiting factor is the shared memory, so I'm gonna try to reduce it or the use a less number of blocks and make extra "calculation loops" per single block. So it should be possible to launch the kernels concurrent.

Comment: @hubs Using less MP by reducing grid size and doing more work per block may enable concurrent kernel exe, but will slow down your each of your kernel. So it won't raise the over-all performance for all your kernels. Reducing shared mem usage may help since it increase the occupancy. You can always __lanuch the kernels concurrently__ but whether they will __run concurrently__ depends on the hardware resource.

Comment: ok, thank you. Probably the only option for real concurrent kernel lauchnes will be, to reduce the use of shared memory.